# How to store an Id beside text and icon in a QComboBox?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qcombobox

is it possible to store some additional data in a QComboBox? I would like to store the Id of a data set beside its caption/name in a combobox, but it shouldnt show up (Ids can be some how cryptic and might confuse the user)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `setItemData`, `itemData` and `findData` methods of `QComboBox`. It allows to attach arbitrary `QVariant` value to each item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This indeed works; I can set and retrieve an additional index programmatically. However, I can't do it by using QT Designer, right?